# I need to get all even numbers from random length 2D Array and make another 2D array with even numbers I've got

Tags: java, arrays

My Java code get all numbers I need, but every row in new array have length like in old array. How to make array with different row length only for numbers I've got?

Please check for my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Help {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int n = random.nextInt(10);
        int m = random.nextInt(10);
        if (n > 0 && m > 0) {
            int[][] arr = new int[n][m];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                    arr[i][j] = random.nextInt(20);
                    System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("***** EvenMatrix *****");
            int[][] evenMatrix = new int[n][m];
            int evenElement = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                    if (arr[i][j] % 2 != 0) {
                        continue;
                    } else
                        evenElement = arr[i][j];
                    for (int k = 0; k < arr[i].length; k++) {
                        evenMatrix[i][j] = evenElement;
                    }
                    System.out.print(evenMatrix[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();

            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(evenMatrix));

        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect array length! Try again!");
            System.exit(0);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what result you're getting that is unexpected?

Comment: The best option is to use an ArrayList Instead of an array. However, if you insist on using an array then you either need to trim the array once finished, or you need to pre-calculate the correct array length before constructing the array so that you don't need to trim it afterwards.

Comment: For example a have array:
2 6 4 7  
1 3 7 5
3 1 7 8
2 9 9 0
4 4 6 6 

even numbers:
2 6 4
8
2 0
4 4 6 6 

so you can see that in first array was :
5 rows by 4 columns
and now i need to do new 2D array with

4 rows with different length

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to help but didn't understand the question well
Let's say your random numbers are 3x3 for n and m

And let's say your array "arr" is

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9}
```

And you want to be your array "evenMatrix" to be

```
[2,4,6,8] n = 1 and m = 4

  or 

[2,4]  n = 2 and m = 2
[6,8]
```

Not n = 3 m = 3 just like in the array "arr"

```
[2,4,6]
[8,0,0]
```

is that right? If so you can check n and m before creating the "evenArray" like

```
    int[][] evenMatrix;
    if(n<m)
        evenMatrix = new int[m][m];
    
    else
        evenMatrix = new int[n][n];
```

creating a square matrix but this still has problems let's say your random numbers are n = 5 and m = 2 so this code will create a 5x5 matrix and fill with even numbers and let's say your randomize arr array doesn't have that many even numbers are so it will become something ugly

Comment: I have arr[5][6], but when i read even numbers from this array i have to do 2d array like this arr[0][2], arr[1][3], arr[2][1], arr[3][0], arr[4][5]

Comment: Sorry, it's my first question here, and I don't understend yet how to format my text)

Answer (score -1):

The easy solution here is to use an `ArrayList`, however, we can also create variable length rows using the following, note the comments below explaining the process, but the key is this `int[][] evenMatrix = new int[n][];`, note how we only specify the column size, not the row size.

Complete code:

```
System.out.println("***** EvenMatrix *****");
//Create 3D array
int[][] evenMatrix = new int[n][];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    //Create inner row that we will trim later
    int[] evenElements = new int[m];

    //Create a counter to track variable locations
    int counter = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] % 2 != 0) {
            continue;
        } else{
            evenElements[counter] = arr[i][j];
            //Incriment counter
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
     }

     System.out.println();
     //Trim the inner array to the correct length that we know from the `counter` 
    evenElements = Arrays.copyOf(evenElements, counter);

    //Assign the inner row of variable length to the 3D matrix
    evenMatrix[i] = evenElements;
}
//Print the result
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(evenMatrix));
```

Example output of the above code:

```
1 11 15 0 15 18 10 
6 12 0 13 15 15 3 
10 13 6 1 12 4 12 
10 7 12 8 19 4 6 
5 10 4 12 4 5 5 

***** EvenMatrix *****
0 18 10 
6 12 0 
10 6 12 4 12 
10 12 8 4 6 
10 4 12 4 
[[0, 18, 10], [6, 12, 0], [10, 6, 12, 4, 12], [10, 12, 8, 4, 6], [10, 4, 12, 4]]
```

Comment: Yes! That's what I need, but I can't use ArrayList in this task. Only arrays

Comment: You can use the same principle, when you create the evenMartix instead of `int[][] evenMatrix = new int[n][m];` you can use `int[][] evenMatrix = new int[n][];` note how we do not specify the length of the rows, only the columns. Then you can create a 2D row of the correct lenghth thta you assign the even numbers to, and then assign in using `evenMatrix[i] = your2Drow;`, this way each row will be the correct length, and you will have a variable with 3D array.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do this way, but I don't understand how to give row length in 2d array. Can you show me code?

Comment: @Zakhar I have updated my answer with a working solution only using an Array. Instead of precomputing the row length we just fill the rows up from the start, and trim the array afterwards `evenElements = Arrays.copyOf(evenElements, counter);`